# Validate input Text field based on complex roles and character position

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

Basically I am a beginner to Angular as well as java script. Here am trying to validate a Reactive form Text field with some conditions.

Conditions are:

1. min value length should 7 and max is 25 .
2. Valid input could be Alphanumeric values along with ‘Asterisk (*)’ from wildcard characters. Though text field allows to enter other special characters but that input is considered as invalid.
3. Asterisk(*) is allowed to give as input from 5th to 13th position , and everything else is considered as invalid after Asterisk(*).
   Eg: 8500*001001…  (Invalid)    8500*  (valid)

   I am aware to write simple custom validations. If any one having idea please help me out or you can suggest me as well. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Forget angular and think about the fundamentals. Write a plain old function and test it. Then use it as a validator.

Comment: can you give an example I don't get the 2,3 point

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi updated.

Comment: example AWEDSSE87898798789  , 789789789797897987879, EWRQ*565656565 ,12345678912*1321 are all these example is valid ??

Comment: can you clear the * , 5-13 point @Royal

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi EWRQ*565656565 ,12345678912*1321  these two are invalid. That 5-13 is  '*' this is allowed only 5th to 13th position  in between.

Comment: 2345678912*1321 is this valid  ???

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi No invalid, After '*' every thing considered invalid.

Comment: In this cas * will be at the end and nothing after it isthiscorrect* *is at 13and nothing after it

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi Exactly !! To implement this which is the best way, either directives or custom validator?

Comment: @Royal I have add my answer , hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

There are may way if you know the regex pattern you can use `Validators.pattern` I recommend writing a custom validator will be easier to maintain and more readable than **complex regex pattern** , and you can provide custom error message about validation of the value , another thing  custom validator is just a function that return an object if the validation is failed or null if the validation succeed.

custom reactive form validator

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms"

export const inputTextValidator = function inputTextValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

  let getErrorObject = function (message): ValidationErrors {
    return {
      inputText: true,
      message // provide custom error message related to the validation role
    }
  }

  let value: string = control.value || '';

  // check if value length between specific range like 7-25
  if (value.length < 7 && value.length < 25) {
    return getErrorObject(`text length must be between 7-25 ,current length ${value.length}`);
  }

  // check if value invalid characters  like #$%^%$^/-+
  let validCharacters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\*]+$/g
  if (validCharacters.test(value) === false) {
    return getErrorObject(`text has invalid characters,current value ${value.length}`);
  }

  let asterisk = /^\w+\*?$/g
  if (asterisk.test(value) === false) {
    return getErrorObject(`only one asterisk at the end of the string is valid,current value ${value.length}`);
  }

  // check the asterisk postion at 8th-13th 
  let indexOfAsterisk: number = value.indexOf('*'); // index base on 0
  if (indexOfAsterisk >= 0 && (indexOfAsterisk < 8 || indexOfAsterisk > 12)) {
    return getErrorObject(`asterisk must bee in postion at 8 -13 th,current * postion ${indexOfAsterisk}`);
  }

  return null;
}
```

> Not in your example you show is the valid position for asterisk start from 5th and this will break the first role about the min length of the value that why I make sure the min is 8 at latest

[**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-validation)