# Angular 6 - reactive form validation pattern doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have an Angular 6 reactive form and trying to validate a password with regex pattern and it doesn't work.

```
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }"
                    />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.pattern">Not valid</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The regex I am usng is like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$')]],

      });
  }
```

Whatever I enter in the password I get the error message in the ui `Not valid`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You may check my answer here about style the state of the reactive form control https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583952/angular-forms-bootstrap-is-invalid-is-valid/51584108#51584108

Comment: I don't know what your regex mean ,sorry but can you check my answer here about  pattern validation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551831/validate-input-text-field-based-on-complex-role-and-character-position

Answer (score 9):

You need to drop ('') and put (//) instead into parameter in your pattern method. 
It should be:

```
password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/)]]
```

Comment: Thanks! worked. (?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&]) needed RegExp and not String.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a second backslash before the d's and remove the '^' and '$' like following example:

```
'(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}'
```